# How do I calculate the speed of a temperature change?

Tags: electricity, temperature

I know how to calculate the change of temperature in a copper wire depending on voltage and current, but not how fast the temperature would change.

Comment: If you know the total amount of heat, total temperature change, and time it takes, then you can compute the temperature change per second : $\frac{Delta T}{t}$. Note also that power $P = V\cdot I$ = heat in per second.

Comment: Doesn't the wire's conductivity decrease with heat making the heat rise faster?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason why it's an exponantial process, the thing is I don't know the total time it takes, that's why I'm asking. And I think you mean P=U*I=[U]*[A]